# Magento2 - Installation

Tags: magento2

Ubuntu
Hello
I would like to create and design an online store by using Magento 2.
I'm planning to install Magento 2.4 on a linux server.

Could you please help me with the following?

1. Which SQL server is more secure and faster (performance) for Magento - MariaDB or MySQL?
2. Which Web server is more secure and faster (performance) for Magento - Apache or Nginx?

Thanks and best regards,

Noury

Answer (score 1):

You can check Magento 2 official recommendation about technology stack: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html